# Ensuring that each letter appears only once in the password

Tags: python, while-loop, set

Just starting learning python and trying to use loop to write codes checking unique letters as follows:

```
def has_unique_letters(x):
  count = 0
  letters = set(x)
  while count < len(x):
    if x[count] in letters:
       return False
    count += 1
  return True
```

However no matter what I input in x, it returns false. What's wrong with the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Every letter of `x` will always be contained in the `set(letters of x)`, therefore your function will always return `False`

To solve your problem, you could verify that the length of `set(x)` is equal to the length of `x`:

**here is why:**

1. A set is a collection of unique objects.
2. The set of the elements of x, is the collection of the unique
   elements composing x.
3. Therefore, if x is composed exclusively of unique elements, the
   cardinality of the set of the elements of x will be equal to the total
   number of elements composing x.

```
def has_unique_letters(x):
    return len(set(x)) == len(x)
```

it returns `True` if x contains only unique letters, and `False` otherwise

#### [edit] - question about indifference to lower/upper case:

If upper & lower case letters in the pw are equivalent, it is necessary to transform the input parameter to lower (or upper) case, prior to processing:

```
def has_unique_letters(x):
    lower_x = x.lower()
    return len(set(lower_x)) == len(lower_x)
```

*[edit] placing a unique letter constraint on a password reduces the domain space; maybe it is not such a great idea.*

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis :)

Comment: Haha as soon as I saw this question I thought "time to use sets" :P tis the shortest way to write it so of course I thought of this approach first :P

Comment: I see where I was wrong but could you explain more why let len(set(x)) == len(x) solve the problem?Thanks!

Comment: I added an explanation Erica Lan

Comment: sorry, one more question. It seems that in this way we can not disregard case that "A"  and "a" are considered the same letter, is there any way we can fix this?

Comment: `set` does not treat `a` and `A` as the same; however, if you want to enforce this, you can transform x to lower case using `x.lower()`, or upper case using `x.upper()`, before returning. (adding to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
def has_unique_letters(string):
    return not bool([x for x in __import__('collections').Counter(string).values() if x > 1])
```